# go handling coroutines variable initialization

Tags: go

Im trying to create goroutines for a http call. I have huge number of URL's.

I create a batch of 200 and send a batch request to the api.

Question:-

1. When I create the client object - client := &http.Client{}, I see a pointer variable is created, will it create a new one for each and every iteration of the for loop? How can I check if the client object created is unique or its pointing to the same one?
2. When I run this program with 250 batches I don't see a issues but once I increase to 270 it fails with an error. Error is given below, Not sure if this is memory error or program error.

   ```
   for _, batch := range data_batch {

           var str_join string = strings.Join(batch, ",")

           // fmt.Println(str_join)
           str_join = "{" + "\"inputs\":[" + str_join + "]}"

           input_json_data := []byte(str_join)

           var output core.Data

           go http_call(respond, &wg, input_json_data, output)

       }


   func http_call(respond chan<- core.Data, wg *sync.WaitGroup, input_json_data []byte, output core.Data) {
       defer wg.Done()



       // clarifai http request URL
       httpurl := os.Getenv("api_url")

       //Create the client Object
       client := &http.Client{}

       //generating the HTTP GET request
       request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", httpurl, bytes.NewBuffer(input_json_data))
       if err != nil {
           log.Println(err)
       }

       // setting authorization

       api_key := "Key " + os.Getenv("api_key")
       request.Header.Add("Authorization", api_key)

       // setting content-type
       request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

       //calling the URL
       response, err := client.Do(request)

       if response.StatusCode != 200 {
           if err != nil {
               log.Println(err)

           }
           log.Println("statuscode = ", response.StatusCode)
       }

       bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
       bodyString := string(bodyBytes)

       err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyString), &output)

       if err != nil {
           print(err)
       }
       respond <- output

   }
   ```

Error:-

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xb5593]

goroutine 261 [running]:
github.com/p/go/utils.http_call(0xc820440d80, 0xc8204317a0, 0xc82052b730, 0x68, 0x70, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
```

Comment: Yes, `:=` creates a new variable. [That is its purpose](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). Generally, don't do that with an HTTP client. Create one and re-use it (or at least the Transport). The nil pointer dereference probably happens because you continue execution even after errors occur, or because you use the response without checking the error first.

Comment: If I create one and reuse it won't it be problem as its a pointer variable..Other coroutines will refer to the same one and override the result?  Regarding the invalid memory address - its because of - socket: too many open files
panic: runtime error

Comment: That error happens because you create way, way too many clients. Each one maintains its own connection pool. Not sure what you mean by "override the result". It's also unclear why you don't just use [http.DefaultClient](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-variables).

Comment: When I create the pointer variable and reuse it, won't the same variable be shared with other co-routines causing confusion..I will check  on defaultclient...

Comment: "The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines." https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client

Comment: its late but can you share rest of log error ?